# Django form textarea doesn't appear in template

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new in Django and I'm trying to create a form. The thing is that when I render the form, the textfield doesn't appear, but the button does.

The project is a twitter-like app, the form is where the user puts the text to then post it.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class TweetForm(forms.Form):
     text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 1, 'cols': 85}), max_length=160)
     country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

view.py:

```
class PostTweet(View):
    def post(self, request, username):
        form = TweetForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            tweet = Tweet(text=form.cleaned_data['text'], user=user, country=form.cleaned_data['country'])
            tweet.save()
            words = form.cleaned_data['text'].split(" ")
            for word in words:
                if word[0] == "#": #Separamos todas las letras del tweet y si empieza con #, se va a crear un hashtag de esa palabra
                    hashtag, created = HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name=word[1:])
                    hashtag.tweet.add(tweet)
        return HttpResponse('/user/' +username)
```

model.py:

```
class HashTag(models.Model):
    #HashTah Model:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    tweet = models.ManyToManyField(Tweet)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
       <form method="post" action="post/">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 fieldWrapper">
               {{ form.text.errors }}
               {{ form.text }}
            </div>
           {{ form.country.as_hidden }}
           <div>
               <input type="submit" value="Post">
           </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
    <div>
        {% for tweet in tweets %}
        <div class="well">
            <span>{{ tweet.text }}</span>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

image of template:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bGh4.jpg)

Comment: Show de get method code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The problem is that you don't passing your form into your template. Your can do it by inheriting `get_context_data` method in your view.
2. Use `FormView` instead of simple `View`, define `form_class` and `template_name`, and it will work. Instead of `post` method, use `form_valid` and `form_invalid` methods to handle vaild and invalid response, if you need. Since you are using `ModelForm`, you can omit all methods and keep this view as simple as possible, just adding `success_url` property to it.

Please read information about ClassBased views, and dig into FormView. It will help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **context_processors**. Below is my use of context processor for 
one of my websites.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            '**newsletter.context_processors.form_signup**'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

*context_processors.py*(This is inside my newsletter app)

```
from .forms import SignUpForm

def form_signup(request):

    context = {'form_signup': SignUpForm()}
    return context
```

Now your **{{ form_signup }}** should appear on any template.

Answer (score 0):

Try add in class, the form class,

```
class PostTweet(View):
    form_class = TweetForm

    def post(self, request, username):
        form = TweetForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            tweet = Tweet(text=form.cleaned_data['text'], user=user, country=form.cleaned_data['country'])
            tweet.save()
            words = form.cleaned_data['text'].split(" ")
            for word in words:
                if word[0] == "#": #Separamos todas las letras del tweet y si empieza con #, se va a crear un hashtag de esa palabra
                    hashtag, created = HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name=word[1:])
                    hashtag.tweet.add(tweet)
        return HttpResponse('/user/' +username)
```