# Using a Django form on more than one HTML page

Tags: python, html, django, forms

In this latest project I'm using a simple contact form, which resolves to the url /email/.  I also want to include this form on the homepage.  In the past I've used get_context_data when I have a page class in a view, but I'm using cookiecutter with crispy forms for the first time and don't know where to do that, or even if that is the right thing to do.

Here's the forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Div, Submit, HTML, Button, Row, Field
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import AppendedText, PrependedText, FormActions
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    content = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)

    # the new bit we're adding
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('contact_name', placeholder="Full Name", autofocus=""),
            Field('contact_email', placeholder="Email Address"),
            Field('content', placeholder=""),
            Submit('sign_in', 'Submit', css_class="btn btn-info"),
            )
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Your name:"
        self.fields['contact_email'].label = "Your email:"
        self.fields['content'].label = "Your message:"
```

...and that renders perfectly at /email/.  How do I get this form to appear on the front page also?

In case it's needed, here's the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^email/$', views.email, name='email'),
    url(r'^success/$', views.success, name='success'),
]
```

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: Not yet...I can't get the below answer to work.

Comment: what is your front page `view` name?success?

Comment: There actually isn't one (unless I'm missing something) - this project is based on cookiecutter-django.

Comment: I have answered this in one of previous questions https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780620/8728905

Comment: Thanks - I'll check out out when I get home!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Create a form.html file and write the following code in it.

"

```
{% for field in form %}
 <div class="form-group">
     <div class="inner form">
         <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
     </div>
     <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="song_title">{{ 
                  field.label_tag }}</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

2. Include this template in your front page using the following on your front page template

```
{% include 'form.html' %}
```

3. Pass your form instance in your views to the template you want the form to showUp, this will ensure that this form shows up on the front-page template as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm not sure I understand the "pass this form in your views" piece.  Can you expand on that please?

Comment: use this return render(request, your_template, {'form': form})

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - that's not working. I added <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% include 'includes/form.html' %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
  </form> to the home page that lives in template/pages/home.html in the main project folder.  In the main project/contact/views I changed the render request to return render(request, pages/home.html,{'form': form_class}) - still doesn't render.